# Iterating through Parameter Array - Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am new to java and am not able to figure out why the second way to iterate through parameters throws an exception. 
Interestingly `param !=null` passes however i get `ArrayIndexOutofBounds` exception later.
I looked at following link. but that's not helping me.
[Iterating through method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408059/iterating-through-method-parameters)

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class TestReflection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<ReflectThis> c = (Class<ReflectThis>)ReflectThis.class;
    System.out.println("public class " + c.getName());
    System.out.println("{");
    Method methods[] = c.getMethods();
    for(Method m : methods)
    {
        if(m.isAccessible())
            System.out.print("    public ");
        else
            System.out.print("    private ");

            System.out.print(m.getName()+"(");
        //System.out.println("Parameteres");
        Parameter[] params = null;
        params = m.getParameters();
            //method 1 for iterating thr params
        for(Parameter p : params)
        {
            if(p ==  null)
                break;
            System.out.print(p.getType()+ " " +p.getName()+",");

        }
        params = m.getParameters();
            //method 2 for iterating thr params
    if(params != null)
        {
            for(int i=0; params[i] != null; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(params[i].getType()+ " " +params[i].getName());
                if(params[i+1] != null)
                    System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(");");
    }

    System.out.println("}");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply looping out of bounds.

```
 for(int i=0; params[i] != null; i++)
 {
      System.out.print(params[i].getType()+ " " +params[i].getName());
      if(params[i+1] != null)
           System.out.print(", ");
 }
```

If you have 2 parameters, ie. `i` goes from `0` to `1`, then you will try to access

```
params[1]
params[2] // out of bounds
```

This will basically always go out of bounds because you try to access one more than the number of elements in the array.

Here's how you can join elements with `,` correctly:

- [Clearest way to comma-delimit a list (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668952/clearest-way-to-comma-delimit-a-list-java)

Comment: Thanks, this way I can use method one to add commas after all but last parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the mistake lies in:

```
for(int i = 0; params[i].....
```

This throws an exception if params is empty. Example: params has in elements. Trying to get the 0th element will be out on bounds.

To ensure this doesn't happen:

```
for(int i = 0; i < params.length && params[i]...
```

Comment: Thanks. I expected params to be null when there is no parameter to the method. But i was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In this line you get an Exception if i is bigger than the last index:

```
for(int i=0; params[i] != null; i++)
```

you have to change to:

```
for(int i=0; i<params.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like intention is to loop on the array and append "," except for last entry. Below should work
Need to check for boundary condition as well

```
        for(int i=0; i<params.length; i++)
        {
            if(params[i] != null)
            {
             System.out.print(params[i].getType()+ " " +params[i].getName());

             if(i != params.length-1)
                 System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
```